# Should I have my contractor redo the underlayment?

Tags: roofing, contractors, underlayment, metal-roof

I’m having my roof redone and on the roof where my roofer is going to install standing seam metal roof he put down Winterguard HT fastened with staples (because it was cold so it didn’t stick well).

The installation instructions say:

> WinterGuard will not adhere to wet or cold surfaces. For cold weather tack down, use only roofing nails. Under no circumstances should staples be used with WinterGuard products.

I talked to my roofer and he said, “it’s fine, everybody uses staples.”

Should I make him redo it or is it actually fine?

Comment: "*because it was cold so it didn’t stick well*"  Applying Heat  to the membrane will insure that it will stick well. Heat, not staples, is the proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if there is an issue with the product at some point in the future, the manufacturer will deny any warranty claim because the installation instructions were not followed.

If this were mine, I'd insist that the installer follow the instructions for the products regardless of what everyone else does.

Comment: +1 for following the manufacturers installation instructions. They’ve voided the warranty.